# "Take a ride" vs "ride the rides"

Tags: word-choice, collocations

Which one is better?

1. **take** a ride in *an* amusement park
2. **ride** the rides in *the* amusement park

Comment: I think I'd use 'take a ride' but 'ride the rides'. In spite of the redundancy in the second.

Comment: You can also say "go on the ride(s)" if you don't like the cognate object.

Comment: Whichever fits what you want to say.  How many rides did you ride?